# Unable to update OpenGL to 4.x from 3.3

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, opengl

The output of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"` is as follows:

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.49.0 / 4.10.0-38-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.1.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.1.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 18.1.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I have tried all these ppas: `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`, `ppa:eek:ibaf/graphics-drivers`, `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates` but still my core profile version is at 3.3. All these help in updating the Mesa version which I know is the latest one currently, however the core profile version is stuck at 3.3 awfully!

My graphics card is AMD/ATI Turks XT Radeon HD 6670/7670 which as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#OpenGL_4.5) page should support OpenGL 4.5.

I have read many askubuntu posts and other webpages none of them helped surprisingly given that it is a very old issue. I am also surprised how difficult it is to update drivers in case of linux! Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Radeon Feature page](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#note_19), the HD 6670/7670 is still only supported with OpenGL 3.3, as it is the *Turks* chip, and not one of *Cypress*, *Cayman*, or *Aruba*. Therefore you will not be able to enable newer versions of OpenGL on the card at this time, with a software upgrade.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I have seen the Radeon Feature page before but still continued to post because of the Wikipedia page I linked in my post, which says that my card supports OpenGL 4.5. Does this mean the wikipedia page is not correct? (You can see that my Graphics card, Radeon HD 7670 is listed in the Radeon HD 7000 series, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_7000_Series#Radeon_HD_7700)

Comment: The Wikipedia page is correct. The hardware does support up to 4.5. The Mesa _radeon_ open source driver however currently only supports 3.3 on that chip. It will only support 4.2 or 4.5 on cards listed on the Wikipedia page, which have the _Cypress_, _Cayman_, or _Aruba_ chips, in the HD 6000/7000 series.

Comment: thank you for clarification. Could you suggest if anything else helps me to upgrade to 4.5? You mentioned radeon open source driver cannot support, does this mean some private/proprietary drivers will support 4.5? If so, may I know where can I get those? Does this also mean I might be able to have OpenGL 4.5 in Windows instead of Ubuntu?

Comment: No. The former catalyst driver may have enabled it, however that driver is no longer supported, and will not work on supported versions of Ubuntu. Not much in Windows uses GL, as DirectX is preferred there, but yes, I suppose the Catalyst driver on Windows will enable OpenGL 4.5 there for anything which does use it instead of DirectX. There is no such thing as "upgrading" to 4.5 though. There's nothing to upgrade in that sense. Your card supports that version of the specification, and the _radeon_ driver in Linux does not. Enablement will require further driver development and testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with the same problem, I have the following hybrid Intel/AMD configuration:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT]`

And I'm stuck in OpenGL 3.3 since Ubuntu 16.04, in Ubuntu 15.10 I had the possibility to use the private `fglrx` driver which updates the OpenGL to the version 4.1

Using the last Kernel and the last Mesa Drivers (Padoka) I don't see any improvement :(

`OpenGL renderer string: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.18.5-041805-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)`
`OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.3.0-devel - padoka PPA`

> The main Point here is, what I understand from this Web [RadeonFeature](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/) is our Graphic Card is included under R600/700, although should be as Northern Islands, which supports OpenGL 4.x :(

Why is this happening?

Comment: I also have a 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09). Where did you read that this intel graphic card is not supported for openGL versions higher than 3.3?